# Azure - Django deployment Static Files

Tags: django, azure, sqlite, deployment, whitenoise

I try to deploy my django app to Azure App Services.
I create App in Azure and deploy my app to Azure. But when i open app i can't see staticfiles (images). However I can see it in locally. By the wat I use `sqlite` for the database.

This is my `settings.py` file:

```py
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images')


MEDIA_URL = '/images/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'static'
]

# Deployment
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

And also this is `urls.py` file:

```py
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

# Deployment
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

First I fogot `DEBUG=True`, but I change it to `DEBUG=False`.
It does not work also.

Comment: It looks good to me. Did you run `./manage.py collectstatic` already?

Comment: Yes, I did it.
I get the same when I set DEBUG=False